# How to update sonar qube project key which contains branch name with slash

Tags: sonarqube

We are running sonar qube 7.0 community version. I know where to find the "update project key" feature.

To preserve our project history from years when switching to Gitflow I'm trying to rename the key from groupId:artifactId:origin/master to groupId:artifactId:origin/develop for some projects. But I get an error message which tells me the slash is not an allowed project key character.

Weired: We have many other projects with key groupId:artifactId:origin/develop or groupId:artifactId:origin/feature-xy.

So it looks like it is possible to **create** a project key with slashes (via maven build with branch.name set) but it is not possible to **change** a project key to such a value? Really?

Is there any way to get the project key changed? I would even use a solution which changes things directly in the database.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

As there seems to be no solution from sonar qube we changed the project key directly in the sonar qube database.

Use the following sql at your own risk.

```
UPDATE projects SET 
NAME=CONCAT(NAME, ' origin/master')
WHERE scope='PRJ' AND project_uuid='yourProjectUuid';

UPDATE projects SET 
kee=REPLACE(kee, 'yourGroupId:yourArtifactId', 'yourGroupId:yourArtifactId:origin/master'),
deprecated_kee=REPLACE(deprecated_kee, 'yourGroupId:yourArtifactId', 'yourGroupId:yourArtifactId:origin/master')
WHERE project_uuid='yourProjectUuid';
```

Beware, for maven multi module project you will need some more sql.